# Drag and drop on a List row in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop, swiftui-list

I have been trying to implement drag and drop on a `List` in SwiftUI. What I'm trying to do is drag a row on a `List` and drop it on a row in the SAME `List`, much like the Reminders app on `iOS`.

Note: It's important to note that I'm not trying to rearrange the list but rather make the dropped item a "child" of that row.

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

struct EditListView: View {
   @State private var items: [Item] = [
      Item(title: "Apple"),
      Item(title: "Banana"),
      Item(title: "Papaya"),
      Item(title: "Mango")
   ]
   
   var body: some View {
      
       VStack {
         List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
               Text(item.title)
            }
            .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate:dropDelegate() )//doesn't work
            
            .onDrag{
                NSItemProvider(item: .some(URL(string: "item")! as NSSecureCoding), typeIdentifier: String() )
            }
         }
           
        Text("Drop Item Here..")
               .fontWeight(.heavy) 
               .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate:dropDelegate() )//works
        
       }
   }
}


class dropDelegate: DropDelegate {

    func performDrop(info: DropInfo) -> Bool {
        print("drop success")
        return true
    }
}
```

Dropping on the `Text` works.

[image]

Dropping on the list row fails.

[image]

Comment: In your final solution do need rearrange and drop into sublist ? or drope to sublist is only necessary ?

Comment: I want to do BOTH move to sublist and rearrange.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer but in playing with this last night I did find that you can drag and drop between two adjacent lists in the way you want, without any special work. So I messed around with two possible solutions that essentially layered two lists and distributed the drag and drop across them. One solution didn't match the default drag interaction in that it didn't raise the item on long press of the drag (you had to move the drag first), the other didn't highlight the cell in the default manner on a hovering drop. Unsure if either of these are of interesst?

Comment: The two layered lists idea sounds really interesting. Anyway, I could have a look at the code even if it isn't a complete answer?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is two problems with your code.

**First** : many article on the web report that the drop is not working on List component, but you can replace the List by a ScrollView. Then the drop method will be called.

**Second**: If you want to apply an action drop by item you have to move you drop method inside the foreach.

In the updated code, I just added a sample cell, you can easily reproduce a cell effect by yourself :

```
struct Sample: View {
    @State private var items: [Item] = [
        Item(title: "Apple"),
        Item(title: "Banana"),
        Item(title: "Papaya"),
        Item(title: "Mango")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    SampleCell(item: item)
                        .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate:dropDelegate() )
                        .onDrag{
                            NSItemProvider(item: .some(URL(string: "item")! as NSSecureCoding), typeIdentifier: String() )
                        }
                }
            }
            Text("Drop Item Here..")
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate:dropDelegate() )//works

        }
    }
}

struct SampleCell: View {
    var item : Item
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(item.title).padding()
            Spacer()
        }.frame(maxWidth:.infinity, minHeight: 60)
        .background(Color.gray)
    }
}
```

Comment: This implementation would make drop and drop on a row possible but it removes the rearrange functionality.

Comment: Ok, so I think you can't actually (November 2021) realise what you want because onMove and OnInsert are only available in List not ScrollView.

Comment: You're probably right. I've seen several unanswered questions regarding this same issue. According to a Apple Developer Technical Support Engineer I spoke to today, both rearrange and drag and drop can be achieved using `LazyVStack`(impossible with Lists). However, there is no documentation on how to achieve this yet, according to DTS.

Comment: @unknown [Here](https://avitsadok.medium.com/reorder-items-in-swiftui-lazyvstack-6d238efab04)'s a working example using `LazyVStack`.

Comment: @meaning-matters that's completely different than using a `List`—you would have to manually implement delete and move UI.